# How can you verify a method with a specific NSpecification parameter in C# unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am currently writing unit tests for a CommandHandler.
I use Moq 4.12.0 and xUnit 2.4.1 for the tests.
I wanted to verify whether that a method was called with a certain [NSpecification](https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications).

I'm pretty new in the unit-testing world.

This is the CommandHandler:

```cs
public class DeleteAlarmCodesCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DeleteAlarmCodesCommand, CommandResult<IEnumerable<AlarmCode>>>
    {
        private readonly Domain.Model.IAlarmCodeRepository _alarmCodeRepository;

        public DeleteAlarmCodesCommandHandler(
            Domain.Model.IAlarmCodeRepository alarmCodeRepository)
        {
            _alarmCodeRepository = alarmCodeRepository;
        }

        public async Task<CommandResult<IEnumerable<AlarmCode>>> Handle(DeleteAlarmCodesCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {            
            ASpec<Domain.Model.AlarmCode> spec = Spec<Domain.Model.AlarmCode>.Any;

            if (request.AlarmId != null)
            {
                spec &= Domain.Model.AlarmCodeSpecifications.ForAlarmId(request.AlarmId);
            }

            if (request.LanguageISO != null)
            {
                spec &= Domain.Model.AlarmCodeSpecifications.ForLanguageISO(request.LanguageISO);
            }

            try
            {
                var alarmCodes = await _alarmCodeRepository.DeleteAsync(spec);
                await _alarmCodeRepository.SaveAsync();

                return new CommandResult<IEnumerable<AlarmCode>>(alarmCodes.Select(x => x.ToViewModel()));
            }
            catch (Domain.ApiDomainException ex)
            {
                return new CommandResult<IEnumerable<AlarmCode>>(ApiErrors.FromException(ex));
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my unit test to check whether the DeleteAsync() is called with the specification.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task Should_DeleteWithAlarmIdOne_WhenCalledWitParameterAlarmIdOne()
{
    // Arrange
    var repo = new Mock<IAlarmCodeRepository>();
    var command = new DeleteAlarmCodesCommand() { AlarmId = 1 };

    var commandHandler = new DeleteAlarmCodesCommandHandler(repo.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await commandHandler.Handle(command, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());

    var spec = Spec<AlarmCode>.Any & AlarmCodeSpecifications.ForAlarmId(command.AlarmId);

   // Assert            
   repo.Verify(x => x.DeleteAsync(spec), Times.Once);
   repo.Verify(x => x.SaveAsync(), Times.Once);
}
```

The problem is that the reference to both objects are different, as they are created when they are needed. So Moq sees them as completely different objects.
Because when I run the test, I get the following result in the result pane.

```
   Duration: 182 ms

  Message: 
    Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.DeleteAsync(x => (True AndAlso (Convert(Convert(x.AlarmId, Int32), Nullable`1) == Convert(value(Services.Domain.Model.AlarmCodeSpecifications+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).alarmId, Nullable`1))))

    Performed invocations:

       Mock<IAlarmCodeRepository:1> (x):

          IAlarmCodeRepository.DeleteAsync(x => (True AndAlso (Convert(Convert(x.AlarmId, Int32), Nullable`1) == Convert(value(Services.Domain.Model.AlarmCodeSpecifications+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).alarmId, Nullable`1))))
          IRepository`1.SaveAsync()

  Stack Trace: 
    Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
    Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)
    DeleteAlarmCodesCommandHandler_Handle.Should_DeleteWithAlarmIdOne_WhenCalledWitParameterAlarmIdOne() line 46
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Is there a way with Moq to verify calls with complex objects, like the Spec.

Or how can I test this better?

**Update**

This is the definition of IAlarmCodeRepository.

```cs
 public interface IAlarmCodeRepository : IRepository<AlarmCode>
    {
        IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }

        Task AddAsync(AlarmCode entity);

        Task<AlarmCode> GetOneAsync(int id);

        Task<AlarmCode> GetOneAsync(ASpec<AlarmCode> spec);

        Task<IEnumerable<AlarmCode>> FindAsync(ASpec<AlarmCode> spec);

        Task<bool> Exists(ASpec<AlarmCode> spec);

        Task<IEnumerable<AlarmCode>> DeleteAsync(ASpec<AlarmCode> spec);

        Task<AlarmCode> DeleteOne(int id);

        Task<IEnumerable<short>> GetDistinctAlarmIds();
    }
```

```
public interface IRepository<T>
         where T : IAggregateRoot
    {
        Task SaveAsync();
    }
```

```
 public async Task SaveAsync()
        {
            await UnitOfWork.CommitAsync();
        }
```

This are the AlarmSpecifications.

```cs
 public static class AlarmCodeSpecifications
    {
        public static ASpec<AlarmCode> ForAlarmId(short? alarmId)
        {
            return new Spec<AlarmCode>(o => o.AlarmId == alarmId);
        }
    }
```

Spec and ASpec comes from the NSpecifications library on https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications :
https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications/blob/master/Nspecifications/ASpec.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some assumptions had to be made because of missing information, but the follow should provide enough of a platform to understand how to exercise the subject under test

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_DeleteWithAlarmIdOne_WhenCalledWitParameterAlarmIdOne() {
    // Arrange
    short? expectedAlarmId = 1;
    var alarmCode = new AlarmCode { AlarmId = expectedAlarmId };
    var alarmCodes = new List<AlarmCode>(alarmCode);

    var repo = new Mock<IAlarmCodeRepository>();
    //fake the desired functionality
    repo.Setup(_ => _.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<ASpec<AlarmCode>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync((ASpec<AlarmCode> arg) => alarmCodes.Where(arg));
    //allow async flow
    repo.Setup(_ => _.SaveAsync()).ReturnsAsync(Task.CompletedTask); //assuming it it void (Task)

    var command = new DeleteAlarmCodesCommand() { AlarmId = expectedAlarmId };

    var commandHandler = new DeleteAlarmCodesCommandHandler(repo.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await commandHandler.Handle(command, default(CancellationToken));


    // Assert
    var expected = Spec<AlarmCode>.Any & AlarmCodeSpecifications.ForAlarmId(command.AlarmId);
    repo.Verify(x => x.DeleteAsync(It.Is<ASpec<AlarmCode>>(actual => actual == expected)), Times.Once);
    repo.Verify(x => x.SaveAsync(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how do I know now that it exactly called the ForAlarmId(alarmId) spec. The SaveAsync was indeed void. I changed it to `repo.Setup(x => x.UnitOfWork.CommitAsync()).ReturnsAsync(true);` The SaveAsync is a "wrapper" around the unitOfWork.

Comment: It is the interface being mocked so it does not matter what the implementation is. the setup should be done on the interface which exposes `SaveAsync`

Comment: Since the exact spec is being constructed within the method under test you will have to infer what us constructed. which is why the filter is applied to a collection it is known to match

Comment: @Scathach check updated alternative, though I prefer my original suggestion

Comment: Thank you for you explaination. I see now how I can use this in other tests too. I marked it as answer.

Comment: I used the original version, but I inserted the SPEC in the setup of DeleteAsync. It seems to work. I will play with it a bit longer.